# Web Site and Database deployment

Tags: .net, sql, iis, deployment

I have started an open source project which consists of a website and a database.

I am at the point of wanting to offer the first release but would like to make it easy for people to install the solution. I have used umbraco and I thought there tool was excellent and would like something like this but I dont know where to start.

Therefore my question is what is the best way to create a deployment tool for a normal person ( non computer type ) to use?

thanks.

Comment: If it's a website, what has to be installed?

Comment: Create an installer in ASP/SQL. Something like what phpBB etc offer.

Comment: Danny: I could use the Web Deploy option is visual studio and publish to a file system then bundle this up. I could also generate the script file for the ms sql database. I could then put both of these in the same zip. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @StephenCossgrove I was talking about rolling your own installer. Can't be too hard!

Comment: @Stephan Cossgrove , Is there any tool that you have discussed. To make a zip file of all those files to upload for publishing and unzip file on website once it is uploaded thr' FTP.